# .show().clone() html different than .clone().show()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sample of what I am talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/bsnxp/1/

If you check the source `.show().clone()` `display` is `inline-block` (what it should be) and `.clone().show()` is `display: block` (not what it should be).

jQuery `.show` documentation (http://api.jquery.com/show/) says "This is roughly equivalent to calling `.css('display', 'block')`, except that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially".

Is there a reason that cloning removes from memory what the original CSS display property was? Is there a better way to bypass this than using .show().clone() then .hide()?

Answer (score 1):

`.clone` without any arguments doesn't copy the element's data - which includes information about what the display was initially.

Use `.clone(true)` to clone the data as well.

Documentation for `.clone()` http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: That argument is `withDataAndEvents` (events and data) and not for what he has mentioned.

Comment: @Vega Not sure what you mean, jQuery stores the initial display value in `.data("olddisplay")`, which is not cloned when you just do `.clone()`. Edit: Apparently that is internal to jQuery. But you can see it in `jQuery.cache`: http://jsfiddle.net/bsnxp/3/

Comment: @Vega I think he is right, if you don't copy over the data, how is jQuery supposed to calculate what the display status was initially?

Comment: @KevinB True.. but some reason it shows me `block` even though the style is `inline-block`? (Testing in FF12 )  @Esailija - You are right and it seems to save the `oldvalue`, I am trying to locate this in source though :)

Comment: `jQuery._data(element)` should be able to fetch jQuery's internal data for the element. http://jsfiddle.net/bsnxp/5/ . You can test the result between data cloned elements and non-data cloned elements.

Comment: +1 from me.. but even `.clone(true)` doesn't seems to fix what he had. or Did it?

Comment: @Vega I'm not sure about that either, but you need `.clone(true)` for sure to copy the `"olddisplay"` from an element. It should answer *Is there a reason that cloning removes from memory what the original CSS display property was?*

Comment: Sorry I modified the question, is there a better way to get by this 'issue/bug' and save the display history after cloning?

Comment: @NoviceCoding the display "history" is copied over when you do `.clone(true)` as shown here http://jsfiddle.net/bsnxp/7/

Comment: Then although the history is copied over when you do .clone(true) that still doesnt explain why .show() doesn't go back to the last one in the history as indicated by the docs. Since I tested it here and didnt work: http://jsfiddle.net/bsnxp/4/

Comment: @NoviceCoding there is no history for the element you are copying in the first place. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/bsnxp/9/